# creating my own customized tumblr theme with my html codings

Tags: jquery, html, css, tumblr

I read Tumblr's instruction on how to make your own theme. But I didn't see any instructions on how to incorporate your own html file to make a customized tumblr theme. So for instance, I would like this div to be the title blog for my custom theme:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <h1>
        <span id="NEW">NEW</span><br>
        <span id="MEDIA">MEDIA</span><br>
        <span id="NEWB">NEWB</span><br>
    </h1>
    <h2>Do's and Dont's for Emerging Digital Media Professionals</h2>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 14px;
    bottom: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#NEW {
    font-family: Broadway;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #880303;
    display: none;
}

#MEDIA {
    font-family: Impact;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #494545;
    letter-spacing: 11px;
    display: none;
}

#NEWB {
    font-family: Showcard Gothic;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: black;
    display: none;
}

h2 {
    position :absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 14px;
    font-family: Britannic Bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#NEW').delay(250).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#MEDIA').delay(850).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#NEWB').delay(1600).fadeIn(1000);
});
});
```

Comment: How far did you get when editing? The Customize option, click Edit HTML. If you've done that, you've looked at the HTML of the current theme and can't see where to put your code?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't [looked hard enough](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)?

Comment: well i guess I said it wrong. I don't understand the concept of blocks and variables. I follow and understand it more when I see a visual example.

Comment: yes I don't follow the tumblrs coding. so where would I put my div code as the title blog?

Comment: Still unclear as to whether you found where to edit the HTML or not. If you have, your best bet is trial and error, the concept of blocks and where to place your code will become obvious. If you mean you don't know where to place which bits (css/js/html) in the HTML then it'd be an idea to learn about HTML structure.

Comment: I know where the css/js/html go in the HTML. But when I go to edit html on tumblr, I get confused. For instance I can't find the part where they have the h1 so I can replace it with my own (the codes on my post)

Comment: I would suggest reading the docs: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#get_started

Comment: You have an error in your javascript, the repeated `});});`

Comment: If you click `Edit HTML`, hit `Ctrl/Cmd + F` and search for words like _title_, _<h1>_ etc. After some fiddling around, you'll find what you need. (What duncan means, the last `});` is too much.)